# React submit form button inside link component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The submit button in the form should perform its assigned function and close the component by returning to the homepage, but if you wrap the button with Link component, the function is canceled. Any ideas how to avoid this?

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/"}} ><button type="submit" value="Submit">Save</button></Link>
```

```
handleEditFormSubmit = (index, e) => {
  if (!this.canBeSubmitted()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return alert("Please fill all empty text spaces");
  } 
  e.preventDefault();
  let products = [...this.state.products];
  products.splice(index, 1, {name: this.state.name,
    ean: this.state.ean,
    type: this.state.type,
    weight: this.state.weight,
    color: this.state.color,
    active: false})
  this.setState({ products, name: "", ean: "", type: "", weight: "", color: "", active: false},
  () => {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to redirect to home page is use history inside function.

```
submitHandler=()=>{
  //do all operation here after this navigate to home page like below example.
   this.props.history.push("/");
}
```

example for your reference

```
  submitHandler=()=>{
   this.setState({name:'Hello'},()=>{
     this.props.history.push("/");
   })
  }
```

You can check this working demo and can understand how to do.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-46dw8

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this.props.history is undefined error. From what I see, the new react versions use BrowserRouter instead of history. I'm also adding the submit function just in case.

Comment: Appreciated, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/LukasSkarnulis/talech-task. The app component has the submit function, and the Editprod component contains the submit button, which should do the function and return to homepage.

Comment: Figured it out by using Redirect component and adding new state. Thanks for the help.